# Multicast MSMQ inside Docker Windows Container

Tags: msmq, multicast, docker-for-windows

We have a legacy windows project, that we would like to containerize.

This uses MSMQ multicasting (part of Telerik's obsolete ORM).

Inside my Windows Container, If I attempt

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Oneline -FeatureName MSMQ-Multicast -All
```

This fails:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : One or several parent features are disabled so current feature can not be enabled.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Multicast -Al ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Also:

```
PS C:\scripts> netcfg -c p -i ms_rmcast
Trying to install ms_rmcast ...

... failed. Error code: 0x800106d9.
```

The container is connected via a 'transparent' network type, so is bridged to the local network.

Is there any solution to this, or is this just not (yet) supported?
Is version 1809 likely to help?
Any other clever ideas?

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ was added in 1803 SAC channel. It does not exist in LTSC channel.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/07/25/hello-world-msmq-from-windows-containers/

Comment: So MSMQ itself installs correctly, just not the *multicast* part.

Comment: I don't know about multicast but MSMQ support was only added in 1803, it was not possible to install MSMQ before at all